# Trigger compiles without errors, But it does not add data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to update the table called 'saturn.szrunsp' after a update or insert happens on the table 'saturn.szraspr'. After kind suggestions i've created a trigger without any errors. however, the main part still doesnt seem to work which is the trigger to add data onto the table saturn.szrunsp after update on table saturn.szraspr. please see all codes of table and trigger below. UPDATED!!

```
-- INSERTING table --

        CREATE TABLE SATURN.SZRUNSP
    (
      SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NO       VARCHAR2(9 CHAR)     NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_PIDM             NUMBER(8)            NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NAME     VARCHAR2(60 CHAR)    NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT  VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)     NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_UNSUSPEND_DATE   DATE                 NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_ACTIVITY_DATE    DATE                 NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_USER_ID          VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
      SZRUNSP_ACTION           VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
      SZRUNSP_SURROGATE_ID     NUMBER(19)           NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_VERSION          NUMBER(19)           NOT NULL,
      SZRUNSP_VPDI_CODE        VARCHAR2(6 CHAR)
    )


-- TRIGGER TABLE -- 

    CREATE TABLE SATURN.SZRASPR
(
  SZRASPR_STUDENT_NO             VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_STUDENT_NAME           VARCHAR2(60 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_DATE_OF_BIRTH          VARCHAR2(8 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT        VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_EMAIL_ADDRESS          VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_STUDENT_YEAR           VARCHAR2(2 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_FACULTY                VARCHAR2(60 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_SCHOOL_OF_STUDY        VARCHAR2(60 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_DEGREE_NAME            VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_MODE_OF_STUDY          VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_FEE_STATUS             VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_YEAR_START             VARCHAR2(4 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_SEMESTER_START         VARCHAR2(5 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_ENROLMENT_STATUS       VARCHAR2(2 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_LEAVING_DATE           VARCHAR2(8 CHAR),
  SZRASPR_PENDING_ACTIVITY_DATE  DATE,
  SZRASPR_ACTIVE_ACTIVITY_DATE   DATE,
  SZRASPR_PENDING_STATUS         VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),
  SZRASPR_ACTIVE_STATUS          VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),
  SZRASPR_PIDM                   NUMBER(8)      NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_TERM_CODE              VARCHAR2(6 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SZRASPR_ASPIRE_ERROR_REPORTED  VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
  SZRASPR_ERROR_TEXT             VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  SZRASPR_SEQ_NO                 NUMBER,
  SZRASPR_SEND                   INTEGER,
  SZRASPR_SURROGATE_ID           NUMBER(19),
  SZRASPR_VERSION                NUMBER(19),
  SZRASPR_USER_ID                VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  SZRASPR_DATA_ORIGIN            VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  SZRASPR_ACTIVITY_DATE          DATE,
  SZRASPR_VPDI_CODE              VARCHAR2(6 CHAR)
);



--Trigger--

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER szrunsp_suspend_trigger
after update or insert on SATURN.SZRASPR
for each row     
declare
    SZRUNSP_USER_ID varchar2(30 CHAR);
begin
    select user into SZRUNSP_USER_ID from dual;

    insert into SATURN.SZRUNSP values
        (:new.SZRASPR_STUDENT_NO,
         :new.SZRASPR_PIDM,
         :new.SZRASPR_STUDENT_NAME,
         :new.SZRASPR_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT,
         SYSDATE,
         SYSDATE,
         user,
         :new.SZRASPR_SURROGATE_ID,
         :new.SZRASPR_VERSION,
         :new.SZRASPR_VPDI_CODE);
 end;
/
```

Comment: `VALUES ( , , ` and `d_account, , , SYSDA` ??

Comment: can do `v_user_id := USER_ID`. But then again, why??

Comment: i've created a system where a user submits some data onto a search field which will then save onto the table 'SZRASPR'.  if the table changes in any way then the trigger should fire and save on to the table 'AUDIT_UNSUSPEND_TABLE'

Comment: That spelling of `'ERROR OCCURED'` seems to be an old IT tradition. Good to see it ;)

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It looks correct syntax wise - are you getting an error?

Comment: @Abdulgood89 yes i am. please see above as i edited the question.

Comment: has your `saturn.szraspr` table a `SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NO` column?

Comment: not exactly. saturn.szraspr has szraspr_student_no column.. in my db every table has a column with their table name first then the column name.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting NULL values into

```
  SZRUNSP_SURROGATE_ID     NUMBER(19)           NOT NULL,
  SZRUNSP_VERSION          NUMBER(19)           NOT NULL,
```

And you can only use the :new prefix for columns on the triggering table - not on the table you're inserting into

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you get this error:

```
[Error] ORA-00947 (9: 20): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

The number of values in the INSERT statement matches the table you posted. So, if you are getting that error you need to correct your question.

```
[Error] PLS-00049 (10: 2): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NO'
```

All the columns referenced in the INSERT statement have the same names as the target table, `saturn.szrunsp`. However the bind names must match the columns of the triggering table. `saturn.szraspr`. You say

> saturn.szraspr has szraspr_student_no column

so you need to edit the trigger to match:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER szrunsp_suspend_trigger
after update or insert on szraspr
for each row     
declare
    szrunsp_user_id varchar2(30);
begin
    select user into szrunsp_user_id from dual;

    insert into szrunsp values
        (:new.SZRASPR_STUDENT_NO,
         :new.SZRASPR_PIDM,
         :new.SZRASPR_STUDENT_NAME,
         :new.SZRASPR_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT,
         SYSDATE,
         SYSDATE,
         user,
         :new.SZRASPR_ACTION,
         '',
         '',
         '');
 end;
/
```

In Oracle an empty string is `null` so you will get NOT NULL violations on  SZRUNSP_SURROGATE_ID and SZRUNSP_VERSION which you need to handle.

Comment: I've done what you guys suggested and the code compiles without any errors. however the trigger doesn't seem to add any data on the table i'm trying to insert it into.

Comment: We cannot debug your environment remotely. So you need to provide a reproducible test case for us.

Comment: reproducible test case? how do you mean?

Comment: Post table structures and sample data which shows the problem